# Avro and Thrift Source in Flume

Tags: avro, thrift, flume, flume-ng

I am new to Flume, Could someone please clarify this question:

As per Flume documentation it provides support for various sources types with its built-in API.Sources like : `Avro source , Spooling Directory source , Exec source ,Netcat Source , Syslog source.`

Suppose we want to fetch data from telnet then we use Netcat as a source.

Then in what kind of scenarios we will use `Avro and Thrift sources`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use both for the Sinks of the same type. As mentioned in the documentation for both, it states that they are "one half of" Flume tiered topology support.

For example, put netcat (or other) sources to an Avro sink, setup a second agent with an Avro source and an HDFS sink to funnel all netcat data to a unified location

[Refer to the Multiplexing & Consolidation sections in the documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

Avro is generally the preferred format because if you write events to HDFS, then all the query engines of MapReduce, Spark, Pig, Hive, etc can easily read the event data

Comment: Hi. Could you please share documentation link? I tried https://flume.apache.org/documentation.html but no luck.

Comment: Click user guide